# Deployment keys in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, azure-devops, ssh-keys

I'm trying to figure out how I should setup an integration between my Team City CI-server with a git repository in microsoft Visual Studio Team Services. Today I'm using GitLab as VCS and I have added a deployment key to GitLab which I have added to Team City for authentication. Are deployment keys available in VSTS? If so - where are they located? And if not - what is the recommended approach to authenticate between a build server and VSTS?

Comment: (psst... gitlab isn't a vcs, but it does manage git repos)

Comment: Do you mean use TeamCity for gitlab 2FA? And what do you want for VSTS, to connect VSTS with TeamCity or gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what deployment keys are but you may find extensions on VSTS market place which may help you to integrate with Team City.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vss-services-teamcity

Comment: That's not really what I'm trying to do, I just want Team City to be able to fetch the source code from VSTS.

Comment: The extension that I mentioned also has the service endpoint and artifact using which you should be able to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522832/how-to-add-the-on-premise-teamcity-service-endpoint-successfully-in-vsts

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) in VSTS with related permission and then use it in Team City.

Answer (score 0):

VSTS doesn't support deployment keys the same way Git does.

If you have room on your team, one way to mimic deployment keys is to create a user with ReadOnly access. You can also scope project access.

A more "VSTS" way to manage deployments is to trigger a build (even if the build doesn't do anything) and publish the files as build artifacts. You can then use [Personal Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts) to query for the files via a REST API.